# How can I create a relation between multiple tables on the same column in Prisma?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have a logging table similar to the one below.There are also two tables vendors and employees.Each time a vendor or employee is deleted the entry does into the logs with the **delete_id** value being the primary **id** column of the vendor or employee table.How can I create a relation such that logs can be connected to the employees as well as the vendors table if where there is a entry in the logs table?

```
model logs{
  id                     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  delete_id              String?   @unique
  type                   String?
}

model employees{
  id                     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                   String?   @unique
}

model vendor{
  id                     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                   String?   @unique
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a one-to-many relationship in the `logs` model to connect it to both the `employees` and `vendors` models. This allows you to connect a log entry to either an employee or a vendor, depending on the source of the deletion.

Sample Schema:

```
model Log {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  deleteId    Int?      @unique
  type        String?
  employeeId  Int?
  vendorId    Int?
  employee    Employee? @relation(fields: [employeeId], references: [id])
  vendor      Vendor?   @relation(fields: [vendorId], references: [id])
}

model Employee {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String @unique
  logs  Log[]
}

model Vendor {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String @unique
  logs  Log[]
}
```